# How to force MSI installation with specified language

Tags: windows-installer, multilingual

I have a 3rd-party MSI package with multiple language transform, the language for MSI is English, when I install this MSI package, it will automatically check setting of *"Regional and Language Options"* in control panel, and run it with certain language.

The question is I can run this MSI with certain language like:

```
msiexec -i setup.msi TRANSFORM=":1028"
```

while I can not run it with English. Are there some method I can use for this problem? Can I disable the automatic choice of the language? Or can I run this MSI with English version directly?

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can launch the MSI with a specific transform by setting `TRANSFORM` property to the actual transform file path. Here are some articles which may help you:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490766(v=technet.10)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/transforms

But if the MSI automatically selects the language, most likely the transforms are applied automatically. In this case you can try setting [`ProductLanguage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/productlanguage) property to set the language you want:

```
msiexec -i setup.msi ProductLanguage="1033"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide ProductLanguage=1033 as a parameter to msiexec command.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, msiexec -i setup.msi ProductLanguage="1033" worked like magic for US English. Thank you very much!
The full list of codes is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/localizing-the-error-and-actiontext-tables